# view not rendered properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, view, render

I have a model - Products, ProductsController and a layout product. I declared the layout inside the controller. added the css/js/images to the app assets folder. I did everything the rails guide told me to do when I want to have a custom layout. But It still doesn't show the layout i declared but shows me the default page without any formatting and settings.

my files are as follows

Products Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout "product"

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
end
```

and my layout file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cool Amazon Products</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Cool Products from Amazon</a>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

<%= yield %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>

</body>
</html>
```

the index.html.erb is the one that is generated by default!.

I am using twitter bootstrap for the UI. Please let me know if i'm missing something inorder to display the correct layout.

Comment: What's the full name of your layout file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant including the path, from the root of your app (ie. from where your `app` directory is).

Comment: its in my app/views/layouts/product.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Ok, weird, that should work.

So, things to check:

1. Are you in *development* environment, or have you restarted your Rails app?
2. Are you using page or action caching, and you're not clearing them?
3. Could it be a caching issue on the web server?

That's about all that could be causing this.

Comment: for some reason ti works when I change my index file like this 

def index
    @products = Product.all

    render :layout => 'product'
  end

Comment: Weird, which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 3.2 

is there anything else I'm missing ?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of, sorry.

Comment: I realized that this happens when I changed my _form.html.erb and made changes the default create method in the controller.

Does changing those have an effect on rendering ?

Comment: Dunno, why don't you update your question with the changes that cause the problem, or a before/after of your two files.